# Cron unable to read property file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, cron, aix

I get these error message from cron (when I check mails)

```
/usr/Mytest/Log_Deleter.sh[3]: ./Log_Deleter.prop:  not found.
```

In my script I have...

```
#!/bin/ksh
. ./Log_Deleter.prop
```

my script and property files are located at  /usr/Mytest

I'm not sure why cron doesn't recognize this file. When I execute from the folder, it works fine, but I don't see why its causing error.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do that :

```
#!/bin/ksh

cd /usr/Mytest
. ./Log_Deleter.prop
```

Or give the full PATH :

```
. /usr/Mytest/Log_Deleter.prop
```

Comment: what is the output of `ls -l /usr/Mytest/Log_Deleter.prop` ?